# Big-O analysis of ratio of log

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

Based on various trial-and-error in desmos, it seems like the following statement is true but kind of unsure about a formal proof.

Any helps/hints are appreciated.

Claim:

$$\forall \epsilon\in(0,1); \frac{\ln(\frac{n^2\epsilon^2}{n-1}+1)}{\ln(\frac{n\epsilon^2}{n-1}+1)}\in O(\frac{\ln(n)}{\epsilon})$$

Comment: what is $n\,\,$?

Comment: natural number at least 2

Comment: Why not just say $O(\ln n)$ on the right?

Comment: It involves the detail of the problem: $\epsilon$ is like a hyperparameter where can optimize an algorithm slightly better,

Comment: So you want a big O constant independent of $\epsilon?$

Comment: Yeah, that's true

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De Facto way- even though writing $\epsilon$ in $\frac{\ln(n)}{\epsilon}$ is redundant.

For simplicity: $ \epsilon = t$

$$ f(n) = \frac{\ln( \frac{n^2 t^2}{n-1} +1)}{\ln( \frac{n t^2}{n-1} +1)}$$

We need to prove that $$ f(n) = O( \frac{\ln(n)}{t}) \\ \text{A.K.A} \\ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{ \ln(n) /t } \ne \infty$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{f(n)}{\ln (n) / t} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{t\ln( \frac{n^2 t^2}{n-1} +1)}{\ln( \frac{n t^2}{n-1} +1) \ln (n)} = t\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\ln( \frac{t^2 n + n- 1}{n-1})} \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln ( \frac{t^2 n^2 + n - 1}{n-1})}{\ln(n)} $$

First limit is not that hard to calculate: $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{\ln( \frac{t^2 n + n- 1}{n-1})} =  \frac{1}{\ln(t^2 + 1)}$$

Second limit can be broken up into again, $2$ limits:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln ( \frac{t^2 n^2 + n - 1}{n-1})}{\ln(n)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(t^2 n^2 +  n-1) - \ln(n-1)}{\ln(n)} \\= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(t^2 n^2 +  n-1)}{\ln(n)} - \frac{\ln(n-1)}{\ln(n)} \\ = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(n^2(t^2 + t^{-1} - n^{-2}))}{\ln(n)} - \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(n-1)}{\ln(n)}  \\ = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2\ln(n) + \ln(t^2 + t^{-1} - n^{-2}))}{\ln(n)} - \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(n-1)}{\ln(n)} = 2 - 0 -1 = 1$$

Thus this whole limit is equal to:

$$ \frac{1}{\ln(t^2 + 1)} $$

Which is not infinity as $t \ne 0$ as it is not in the interval $(0,1)$

Comment: Great analysis, super appreciate for the effort.

Comment: @laziestperson1 You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

1. You can more easily say $O(\ln(n))$ here, because Big-O ignores multiplicative constants (and $\epsilon$ is a constant here).
2. The denominator clearly converges to a constant. So, you only need to worry about the numerator.
3. The inside of the logarithm is visibly asymptotic to $\epsilon^2n$. Try factoring $\epsilon^2n$ out (and using $\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)$ and easy limits) to rewrite this expression in terms of $\ln(n)$.